# Retrieving values of Firebase Database, nested data

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my JSON nested DB looks:

[image]

Its a `pets` root that has multiple unique IDs. Then each ID represents a pet with some properties, some of them (like `feedingList` and `walkingList`) also contain more values inside that represent meals/walks and their time and completion Boolean.

I have written code in Swift to retrieve some of the values, but I have problem reaching those `fList` and `wList`.

```
func getPetInfo() {

        let refMeals = reff.child("pets")
        refMeals.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapCast = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                for snap in snapCast{
                    if self.currentUser.pets.contains(snap.key) {
                        if let x = snap.value["name"] as? String{
                            self.tempPet.name = x
                            print(x)

                        }
                        if let y = snap.value["type"] as? String{
                            //self.tempPet.type = y
                            print(y)

                        }
                        if let z = snap.value["age"] as? Int{
                            //self.tempPet.age = z
                            print(z)
                        }
                        print(snap.value["fList"])
                         if let w = snap.value["fList"] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                            for snippete in w {
                                if let a = snippete.value["time"] as? String{
                                    //self.tempPet.feedingList.append(a)
                                    print(a)
                                }
                                if let b = snippete.value["doneForToday"] as? Bool{
                                    //self.isItDoneForToday.append(b)
                                    print(b)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if let r = snap.value["wlist"] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                            for snippete in r {
                                if let c = snippete.value["time"] as? String{
                                    //self.tempPet.feedingList.append(a)
                                    print(c)
                                }
                                if let d = snippete.value["doneForToday"] as? Bool{
                                    //self.isItDoneForToday.append(b)
                                    print(d)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //self.petArray.append(self.tempPet)
                    }
                }
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

It all prints out okay for `name`, `age` and `type`, but when it comes to this line of code:

```
 if let w = snap.value["fList"] as? [String:AnyObject]
...
```

It doesn't let it and nothing prints out. Can you tell me where I'm wrong? I'm clearly having trouble understanding values and arrays of this JSON tree. It's a mess when I'm trying to understand what to `get` and convert to what. Thanks in advance.

This is what gets printed out:

```
blasted
cat
3
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x60800024f000>(
{
    doneForToday = 0;
    time = "12:00";
}
)
)
```

Comment: It seems fList and wList are Arrays not Dictionaries !

Comment: What do you mean? I mean in the same way "pets" (in my database on the first picture up there ) is presented as a dictionary with   
[strings that are IDs : AnyObject that has more stuff in],  
 i wanted those fList elements to represent as   
[Strings that are number: AnyObject that has more stuff in]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 if let r = snap.value["wlist"] as? [Int:AnyObject]{
                        for snippete in r {
                            if let c = snippete.value["time"] as? String{
                                //self.tempPet.feedingList.append(a)
                                print(c)
                            }
                            if let d = snippete.value["doneForToday"] as? Bool{
                                //self.isItDoneForToday.append(b)
                                print(d)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //self.petArray.append(self.tempPet)
                }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't fix the problem. I've set the value of those "0" and "1" ... to be a String, so it's not an Int.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen can you help me out here?

Comment: can you think of any other reason why this doesnt work. Im stuck on this and dont know how to proceed

Comment: Yes they work. I updated the question with console prints

Comment: @Dravidian  [Could you please have a look at my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212468) as I am struggling to understand how to dig deeper into the snapshot.